# How to generate executeable jar file using eclipse with multiple packages

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, junit, jar

I am writing a a GUI that is able to run a series of JUnit tests using a third party plug-in to connect to a device.

My trouble is creating an executable jar-file that is able to run the GUI and the JUnit tests. I've tried almost everything.

My GUI is in a separate package while the third party tool is in it's own separate package and is having a lot of dependencies in other packages. I can successfully run the entire program when I run it through eclipse, but as soon as I export it only the GUI component is run as it appears.

Using the export feature in eclipse just gives me a single file that runs the GUI, but as soon as the GUI is supposed to invoke the 3rd party tool nothing happens and a "WinPos" file is created. It seems as if the 3rd party tool is started as it has a few windows that start up, but these are closed and it seems as the program is terminated. I am assuming that some of the dependencies are missing.

I want to generate a jar file that can execute the entire program as it was run through eclipse.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Mi first suggestion:

Add your own `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file to your jar package. You should use it to declare a specific `class-path` which include all the JARs needed for execution.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

(Maybe you find interesting to set also a `Main-Class` attribute.)

And, of corse, when you deploy your application, include all the needed JARs along with your jar.

Comment: So I should first make "jar"s of all the other files in the project before I generate a runnable jar file of my GUI? 

Isn't there a simpler way to keep it all in one .jar file?

The GUI is not a finished program, but something I will be working on continuesly and I will need testers for it, so it would be nice for me to just build the entire program every time I compile it. So that I can then distribute it to my testers.

Comment: What should the "class-path" be? When I check the Manifest.mf file that is generated inside the .jar file it is missing a class path.. or rather it just has: "Class Path: ." (that is a single dot). And looking through the manifest it has no reference to my 3rd party tool, I do however not know if this is nescesary..?

Comment: I was assuming your Eclipse project had dependencies on other external JARs. Isn't it so? Moreover: How is exactly your "3rd party tool" deployed? Is it a JAR file?

Comment: My 3rd party tool is written by a "friend" and is a set of classes that makes up a program without any main "method".

Comment: It doesn't matter if it has no `main`, but it's a MUST that every Java API be properly packaged into a JAR before being distributed. That's what your friend should do. In case he/she won't, you should do it.

Comment: How is this then done? Do I simply take every single "class" file from every single package and export them into a .jar type file or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You said it in your post: To create a JAR file it is enough to export the whole project as "JAR file".

Comment: However when doing this my program doesn't work when I try to run it.. As I explained in the Question

Comment: Well, at this point, I think it is necessary for you to update your post to explain in detail how is project set up: What source folders does it contain, what projects and external libraries it depends upon, etc. And what do you get when you build an executable jar and what does it contain.